# Android Authentication using MSAL

Tags: android, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to implement Authentication using MSAL for Android app but I can't figure out how to get this:
[image]
[enter link description here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android)

I figured out so I need to create signing keys for my application
the instruction here - [enter link description here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/wiki/MSAL-FAQ#redirect-uri-issues)

I can not understand how to implement it. Please help me if somebody had experience with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering this because you have not added the key of apk in the Configuration of the Android application.

In the redirect_uri, the `<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>` part refers to the package name returned by the `context.getPackageName()` method. This package name is the same as the application_id defined in your build.gradle file.

> NOTE: This is the minimum required configuration. MSAL relies on the defaults that ships with the library for all other settings. Refer to the configuration file [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-configuration) to understand the library defaults.

In this case`<YOUR_BASE64_URL_ENCODED_PACKAGE_SIGNATURE>`. This is the key of signed application.
This value cannot be static. You need to provide Microsoft that this application is Authenticating against the real app.

After [registering your app in AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android#integrate-with-microsoft-authentication-library) it will prompt a
`keytool -exportcert -alias SIGNATURE_ALIAS -keystore PATH_TO_KEYSTORE | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`. From this command you can generate the signature of the android keystore keys.